retrieving the decimal values from the keys pressed in RISC_V Digital Lab Sim
I'm trying to obtain the decimal values from the key that I have pressed in Digital Lab Sim in RARS. I know how to read the keycode like 0xffffff81 representing the number 3 to the console. I don't know to extract exactly number 3, or "f" as 16, or "a" as ten instead of the keycode. Is there a way to do this.
I thought the keycode was the address for the key and tried to extract the value from that address into a register. So I tried to print it out but it didn't work.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.


First row: keycode for 0 is 0x11; keycode for 1 is 0x21; keycode for 2 is 0x41; keycode for 3 is 0x81.
Next row: keycode for 4 is 0x12; for 5 is 0x22; 6 is 0x42; 7 is 0x82, and so on for the next rows.

So there's a mapping from each possible keycode to its numeric value labeled on the button.
Software using this primitive hardware interface will have to implement some form of this mapping.
There's many ways mappings can be accomplished: switch/case statement, array lookup, bit twiddling/formula, combination of the above, etc..

Further, to read out keycodes (reading a byte using address 0xffff0014), you have to check each row individually (using address 0xffff0012 to inform (store into) the device which row you're going to be asking about next with 0xffff0014).
So, practically speaking that means you need to loop across the rows (first storing into 0xffff0012) to indicate to the device what information it should return for an inquiry to 0xffff0014.  The first non-zero value indicates a key was pressed in that row, and presumably we don't continue to check further rows until later.

I don't know how the timing works as to when the keycode being pressed is no longer indicated by the hardware.  (Is it that reading the code clears it, as is the case with some other devices?)
The Digital Lab Sim is found in both RARS (RISC V simulator) and MARS (MIPS simulator from which RARS is derived).  So, answers to questions about the RARS version might be found in similar Q&A for MARS.
